# Azure DevOps Test.csproj" was not found

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I get this error while running Azure Function in Azure DevOps Pipeline. 
**error highlighted in Bold**

Build started 11/17/2019 10:44:54 AM.
Project "d:\a\1\s\Hermes.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
**##[error]d:\a\1\s\Hermes.sln.metaproj(0,0): Error MSB3202: The project file "d:\a\1\s..\Hermes.Test\Hermes.Test.csproj" was not found.**
d:\a\1\s\Hermes.sln.metaproj : error MSB3202: The project file "d:\a\1\s..\Hermes.Test\Hermes.Test.csproj" was not found. [d:\a\1\s\Hermes.sln]
Project "d:\a\1\s\Hermes.sln" (1) is building "d:\a\1\s\Hermes.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:

**##[error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.**

Answer (score 1):

[Sample Build pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ldbs6.png) Use .Net core task and use the correct folder path for the project like in the image.